# SELECT all EXCEPT results in a subquery

Tags: mysql, subquery, not-exists

I have a query that joins several tables (3 or 4) and gets me results as expected.

```
SELECT DISTINCT test_title, stt_id FROM student_tests
LEFT JOIN student_test_answers ON sta_stt_num = stt_id 
JOIN tests ON stt_test_id = test_id
WHERE student_test_answer_id IS NULL
```

I have another query that shows another set of data, it basically is this:

```
    SELECT test_id, COUNT(*) AS theCount FROM tests
    JOIN test_questions ON test_id= tq_test_id
    WHERE type= 'THE_TYPE'
    GROUP BY test_id
    HAVING theCount = 1
```

So basically I want to NOT include the results of this second query in the first one.  the test_id would be the joining fields.

I have tried a  WHERE NOT EXISTS ( -the above query -) but that returns no results which is not correct.  I also tried 'NOT IN ( )'

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Without seeing your actual query, I'd venture to guess that your subquery was not correlated.

Comment: post please your real queries, samples of data and expected result. your explanation is not very clear, and your query is not clear either: `test_id= tq_test_id` - we have no idea what table those columns belong to

Comment: How exactly did you try `NOT IN()`? If you want to use this query as subquery don't need the theCount in the resultset.

Comment: @Philipp  Well, I couldn't use that because of the count/group by so I had to scrap that idea.

Comment: Yeah but what do you need the count for if you want to exclude data from the other resultset? You can keep your having clause, but not on the alias but on the actual count(*)

Comment: I added the first query

Comment: you have `test_title, stt_id` in first query and `test_id, COUNT(*)` what do you want to check for _existing_?

Comment: I believe by adding LEFT JOIN to the answer of @BHubbard below, and putting that in my main query gives  me the results I needed after testing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
(SELECT test_id, COUNT(*) AS theCount FROM tests
JOIN test_questions ON test_id= tq_test_id
WHERE type= 'THE_TYPE'
GROUP BY test_id
HAVING theCount = 1) outer
LEFT JOIN (
      [OtherQuery]
) a ON outer.test_id = a.test_id 
WHERE a.test_id IS NULL
```

Comment: I am pretty sure this is what I needed.

Comment: I dont know what his query returns, but the structure of it seems to be working.  I think others above may have done the same.  Of course I added this as "LEFT JOIN (ANSWER)" into my main query.  Above is only the relevant part I needed.

Comment: @Alex Sarcasm I guess?  I will say the others seemed to put more time in it and formatting.  But I guess I will choose the answer that worked for me.  The community will just upvote the best one which is all I ever look for.

Answer (score 1):

As written in the comment you should be able to do it like this:

```
SELECT
   DISTINCT test_title,
   olc_stt_i_num 
FROM
   student_tests  
LEFT JOIN
   student_test_answers 
      ON olc_sta_i_stt_num = olc_stt_i_num   
INNER JOIN
   ol_class_tests 
      ON stt_test_num = test_num  
WHERE
   student_test_answer_id IS NULL   

   -- added this: replace test_id with real column 
   AND ***test_id*** NOT IN (
      SELECT
         test_id 
      FROM
         tests      
      JOIN
         test_questions 
            ON test_id= tq_test_id      
      WHERE
         type= 'THE_TYPE'      
      GROUP BY
         test_id      
      HAVING
         COUNT(*) = 1  
   )
```

Comment: I just wonder: hwo do you know that `test_id` column exists in `student_tests` or `student_test_answers` or `ol_class_tests `? do I missed it somewhere?

Comment: No, it is just as a placeholder for the actual column with the id, gonna mark it as such. OP implied there is such column as only the count(*) in the select of the subquery was messing up his query

Answer (score 1):

Here is my answer.   Left outer Join gives you the participant (test). If there are no matches in test_questions then it'll still return the test rows, but null for test_questions.  So if you then look for any test_question.test_id that is null, you will get what you are looking for.

I would also be specific in your count clause and not do a count(*) just to ensure that mysql knows what you truly want to count.

```
create database test;
use test;

create table test
(
    test_id int, 
    `the_type` varchar(20)
);

create table test_questions
(
    test_question_id int,
    test_id int,
    `the_type` varchar(20)
);

insert into test values (1, 'history');
insert into test values (2, 'chemistry');
insert into test values (3, 'reading');

insert into test_questions values (1, 1, 'hard question');
insert into test_questions values (2, 1, 'medium question');
insert into test_questions values (3, 2, 'hard question');
insert into test_questions values (4, 2, 'easy question');

select * from test;
select * from test_questions;

select t.test_id, count(distinct t.test_id)
from test t
left outer join test_questions tq on tq.test_id = t.test_id
where
    tq.test_id is null
group by
    t.test_id
```

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is the second query? I only see one query here, and no sub-query. Also, a sqlfiddle of your precise schema would be helpful.

Anyhow, I think you want some sort of left excluding join. It looks something like this:

```
select     test.test_id, count(*) as theCount
from       tests test
join       test_questions tq
on         tq.test_id = test.test_id
left join  tests excluded_test
on         excluded_test.test_id = test.test_id
where      tq.type = 'THE_TYPE'
and        << Some condition that explains what excluded_test is >>
and        excluded_test.test_id is null
```

EDIT: Yeah, there's definitely a lot of details missing from the original question (which had in some ways been mended), and which are still missing. Knowing the full table-structure of your example is important here, so it is difficult to provide a good concrete answer.